# PHP: call to an instance method via ClassName::method syntax, results in a static call?

Tags: php, static-methods

Her is my code:

```
class MyClass 
{
   public $prop;
   public function method ()
   {
     echo $this->prop;
   }
}
```

Then somewhere in the code, accidently:

```
MyClass::method();
```

I would expect to have an interpretation error about the above line, because the called method is not static. Instead, the method was called, and I received an exception about $prop not existing. So i understand that the method was called as a static method, even though it's not.

Does it work this way? (Why the hell? )

Comment: Check your error reporting, they may just be hidden, look for your error_log near your main file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Calling non-static methods statically generates an E_STRICT level warning.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

I suppose you have E_STRICT warnings suppressed. It works (likely for legacy reasons), but it's not recommended.

Answer (score 4):

For legacy reasons, any class method could be called statically even if it wasn't declared `static`, because you previously couldn't declare them as such. In those cases, `$this` would simply refer to nothing because it's not an object-context variable.

In PHP 5 you get an `E_STRICT` warning for calling non-static methods statically (as you just did).