# Why can non static member function be called this way?

Tags: php, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: call to an instance method via ClassName::method syntax, results in a static call ?!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664511/php-call-to-an-instance-method-via-classnamemethod-syntax-results-in-a-static)

```
class A
{
   function foo()
   {
       if (isset($this)) {
           echo '$this is defined (';
           echo get_class($this);
           echo ")\n";
       } else {
           echo "\$this is not defined.\n";
       }
   }
}

A::foo();
```

Is this a bug or feature?

Comment: This was asked just now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664511/php-call-to-an-instance-method-via-classnamemethod-syntax-results-in-a-static

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's allowed, but definitely discouraged.  [According to the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

> Calling non-static methods statically generates an E_STRICT level warning.

Comment: @zerkms: Not really, he asked why non-static methods can be called statically.

Comment: @BoltClock: why did he emphasize `$this` being not set then?

Comment: @zerkms: Probably because it's the only obvious way to check if a method was called in a static context or object context (besides the call stack).

Comment: @BoltClock: it's not a way to check that. Because: `class A{ function B() { echo get_class($this);}} class C { function D() { A::B(); } } $b = new C; $b->D(); // C`

Comment: @meze: Interesting. And if you declared `A::B()` static it would output A, as if C became A somehow. Very interesting...