# PHP Calling A Method Statically; Even Though Its Not Defined As Static

Tags: php, static-methods

How is this working? Shouldn't this throw an error, since I am trying to call a non static method statically? Basically, I've never instantiated an object of type something.

```
class Something {
   public function helloworld() {
       echo 'hello world';
   }
}

Something::helloworld();
```

Comment: Nothing special, just `$this = null`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: call to an instance method via ClassName::method syntax, results in a static call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664511/php-call-to-an-instance-method-via-classnamemethod-syntax-results-in-a-static)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this at the top of your script:

```
error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT ); // E_STRICT is important here
ini_set( 'display_errors', true );
```

... and see what happens then:

> Strict Standards: Non-static method Something::helloworld() should not
>   be called statically in [...]

Admittedly, it more of a notice than an error though. Your script will happily continue to run.

Answer (score 0):

It would only give you an error, if within `helloworld()` you'd be using `$this`.

It's a type of PHP "WTF" resulting from missing specs that allows you to statically invoke a function not actually declared `static`.

Comment: IIRC, it's not a missing spec, it's just backwards compatibility to PHP 4.

Comment: ...for which there are no specs.

Comment: Well, it's not written word by word, but if you read the [PHP 5 docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) it's clearly written that unspecified is like public. And in PHP 4 public functions could be statically called. So actually it's documented, even inside the static chapter. See as well: http://php.syntaxerrors.info/index.php?title=Call_to_undefined_function#NOTE:_Static_methods_in_PHP4 - Just FYI, normally you should not care that much about PHP 4 any longer.